# Adobe air content:\\com.android.contacts\display_photo\ load a photo

Tags: android, air, air-native-extension

Could I get / load an image from my profile the url is like that

content:\com.android.contacts\display_photo\ 
 without serialize it it using ANE.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't but We build a native extension that will replace that uri by a path a file.